# xargs to concatenate extension onto an argument

Tags: awk, xargs

I am trying to set up a script to automatically delete a `.torrent` file based on an output from `transmission-remote`.

```
transmission-remote http://localhost/transmission -l | grep 100% | grep Finished | awk '{print $10}' | xargs -I% -r -p -n 1 /bin/rm /mnt/samba/Dropbox/%.torrent
```

Here is my current output:

```
/bin/rm /mnt/samba/Dropbox/MyTorrent.torrent ?...y

/bin/rm: cannot remove `/mnt/samba/Dropbox/MyTorrent.torrent': No such file or directory
```

The name that is outputted is identical to the .torrent name

```
root@mfalc:/mnt/samba/Dropbox/# ls
MyTorrent.torrent
root@mfalc:/mnt/samba/Dropbox/#
```

Here is also what it looks like before the `awk`

```
root@mfalc:~# transmission-remote http://localhost/transmission -l | grep 100% | grep Finished | grep Done 
  12   100%  174.4 MiB  Done         0.0     0.0   0.01  Finished     MyTorrent
```

I have obscured the actual torrent name but, does anyone have any suggestions? Am I concatenating the `.torrent` extension with `xargs` correctly?

Comment: Does the torrent name contain whitespace characters?

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier (I totally thought I set up email notifications for post responses) anyway, no there is no whitespace in them.  I am going to try both of these answers this weekend. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't need `xargs` for that, `awk` can do it for you (only that part):

```
awk '{print $10 ".torrent"}'
```

Even better `awk` can call `rm` on it:

```
awk '{system("rm -i " $10 ".torrent")}'
```

If you have space(s) in the torrent names:

```
awk '{system("rm -i " gensub(" ","\\\\ ","g",$10) ".torrent")}'
```

Comment: (now that finals were over I finally had time to do this) Thanks! this one worked

Answer (score 0):

Perl can do this without the need for `grep`, `awk` or `xargs`.

```
perl -lane 'if (/100%.*Finished/) { unlink "$F[9].torrent" or warn $! }'
```

The `-n` option will process all incoming lines, acting as `xargs`, the `if` statement will act as your `grep`, and `unlink` as `rm`. The `warn` is not strictly necessary, but it might be nice to know if the script fails to delete a file.

So you would call it like so:

```
transmission-remote http://localhost/transmission -l | perl -lane 'if (/100%.*Finished/) { unlink "$F[9].torrent" or warn $! }'
```